# Getting an error 'BadRequestException' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie in python and django. Trying to setup django to work with Dropbox but keep getting error "'BadRequestException' object has no attribute 'get'". Here is my code.

```
def get_dropbox_auth_flow(web_app_session):
    APP_KEY= '****'
    APP_SECRET = '****'
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/dropbox"
    return DropboxOAuth2Flow(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, redirect_uri, web_app_session, "dropbox-auth-csrf-token")

# URL handler for /dropbox-auth-start
def dropbox_auth_start(request):
    authorize_url = get_dropbox_auth_flow(request.session).start()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)

# URL handler for /dropbox-auth-finish
def dropbox_auth_finish(request):
    try:
        access_token, user_id, url_state = get_dropbox_auth_flow(request.session).finish(request.GET)
        # oauth_result = get_dropbox_auth_flow(request.session).finish(request.query_params)
    except oauth.BadRequestException as e:
        return e
    except oauth.BadStateException as e:
        # Start the auth flow again.
        return HttpResponseRedirect("http://localhost:8000/dropbox_auth_start")
    except oauth.CsrfException as e:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    except oauth.NotApprovedException as e:
        raise e
    except oauth.ProviderException as e:
        raise e
```

I am following the documentation [here](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#module-dropbox.oauth)

Adding traceback [here](https://pastebin.com/VubTWW3i)

Comment: perhaps you meant `request.get()`? Parens are needed because this is a function call.

Comment: Include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: @Galen added the traceback in my original question

Comment: It's not clear how the code you posted relates to the traceback you posted (it is best to include the actual text of the traceback in the question instead of a link).

Comment: The actual text is in the link that I posted (pastebin)?

Answer (score 0):

For all the other exceptions, you `raise e`, but for BadRequestException you return it - hence the error.

Note that all this is a very strange thing to do. There's no point catching exceptions only to re-raise them. You should only catch the ones that you actually want to deal with, ie BadStateException and CsrfException; you should remove the other blocks altogether and let them be caught upstream.